# Animation not responding on time

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to create a Jquery animation in which one object moves from left to right until it reaches a certain position on the window. Then the object should move all the way back to its origin. What is happening is that it seems the code is responding accordingly and upon reaching 300 it is changing the variables from 200 to -200 to enable the object to go back but it seems the object itself reacts late and won't change direction but until it reaches the end of the window. Here is the code:

```
var speed = 200;
var limite = 300;
var posLeft;

function animeCosa(){
    posLeft = parseInt($("#circulo").offset().left);
    if(posLeft > limite){
        speed = -200;
    }
    $("#circulo").animate({left : "+="+speed},
    3000,
    "linear");

}

setInterval(animeCosa,1000);
```

thanks in advance

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't comment yet. So not really an answer, but is it perhaps because the animation runs for 3000 ms while the setInterval function you're calling it in runs for 1000 ms?

Comment: Well that makes total sense. Will try it out to see what happens thanks !!